# How to pass serialized data to php, laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, laravel

I am using http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/
I'm fine working with forms, but as it is `<ol>'s and <il>'s`, not regular form, I have **no idea** how to pass this data to laravel. I manage to get output into view:

```
....
onDrop: function (item, container, _super) {
  $('#serialize_output').text(group.sortable("serialize").get().join("\n"))
  _super(item, container)
},
....
```

Returns:

```
 Item1,Item2,Item3,... so on
```

In:

```
<h3>Serialize result</h3>

<pre id='serialize_output'></pre>
```

Now, what do I do with this data? How do I tell laravel to grab it and perform some actions in controller? I have no idea how to pass this even to php.

I mean, I could write in view something like `<?php $var = '?> <pre id='serialize_output'></pre> <?php '; ?>` then strip commas, pass to array, into hidden form field or smth, but obviously this is not how its done. What is the right way to handle it?

Would this work: ? http://laravel.io/bin/1yn7e

If yes, what do I do next?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
//...

onDrop: function (item, container, _super) {

    var data = group.sortable("serialize").get();

    $.post('some/url', data:data, functin(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
    });

    // ...
}
```

Server side (Laravel):

```
use Illuminate/Http/Request;
use more...;

class SomeClass extends BaseController {

    // URL/Route: Route::post('some/url', '...');
    public function getData(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->get('data'); // Get the data from $_POST array
    }
}
```

The thing is that, if you use a `POST` request then declared route using something like following: `(Route::post('some/url'))` will get dispached and using `$request->all()` you may get all data, just `var_dump/dd($request->all())` and check the results. Hope this helps to understand the process.

Comment: Yes, you can use `patch` as well but keep on mind that, you need to pass the `_method=patch` to server through the `AJAX` request so that hidden field must be in the form or you manually send it through other data.